# Master to master MySQL 5.7 replication

Tags: mysql, replication

Been trying to get my local machine and a digital ocean droplet's mysql databases to sync for the past 3 hours.

I've followed every tutorial online and can't seem to get it to work.

The only useful error I get when I log out show slave status \G; is -

Last_IO_Errno: 2003
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master

When I dig into my log files, my local machine has the error "2017-03-31T20:33:02.321213Z 11 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'replicator@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1, Error_code: 2003"

and my droplet has the errors

2017-03-31T20:30:08.107370Z 14 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'replicator@xxx.x.xxx.xxx:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1, Error_code: 2003
2017-03-31T20:30:28.995840Z 6 [Note] Aborted connection 6 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'replicator' host: 'pool-xxx-x-xxx-xxx.nwrknj.fios.verizon.net' (failed on flush_net())
2017-03-31T20:32:08.168369Z 14 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'replicator@xxx.x.xxx.xxx:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 2, Error_code: 2003

This is the main tutorial I tried using, and redoing at least 5 times.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? I've been searching for hours and can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you behind a NAT? What are you trying to accomplish with this setup?

Comment: I have a game I'm developing, and everytime I make a change to my local database I want it to change on the database on my hosted server as well. But yes, i'm using my homes network.

Comment: Then I'd bet your NAT is interfering. There are almost certainly better ways of accomplishing whatever it is you're trying to do by having these changes replicate.